# Firebase analytics are not showing on unity project

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I am having a problem while attaching the Firebase analytics Unity SDK with my Unity game project.

I have imported the Unity analytics package in my project from the Firebase website and the Google json file from my console.

I created a simple script on a GameObject and pasted the following code. After opening the apk on my device it doesn't show any realtime analytics at all.

Unity version 2020.3.11f1 (LTS)

```
void Start()
{
    FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            Debug.Log("Available");
            // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
            // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
            FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

            // Set a flag here to indicate whether Firebase is ready to use by your app.
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
            // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
            Debug.Log("Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.");
        }
    });
    Fun();
    Fun2();
}


public void Fun()
{
    FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.EventAppOpen);   
}
public void Fun2()
{
    FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("Fun2");
}
```

Comment: I don't think the SDK is initialized by the time you call `FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent`. You should wait until the `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync` callback is called. The comments in Firebase sample code (included in your code) suggest to set a flag to tell the rest of your app the SDK is ready.